# How to use common module api into a service in standalone approach

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular-standalone-components

I have a service in my application that I need to use Pipe inside it.
In the app.module.ts file I didn't import commonModule in import array because I use Standalone approach.

the app.module.ts import array is:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    IconsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  ...
```

and my service is like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ExportService {
  constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {}
...
}
```

I can fix the problem with adding CommonModule in app.module.ts import array like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    **CommonModule,** <-- Added in here
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    IconsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  ...
```

But is there another way to achive this and without importing CommonModule in appModule file?

Comment: You can directly use the ExportService in the Component you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not inject decimalPipe in constructor

You can create a new [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

```
import { DecimalPipe} from '@angular/common';
import { LOCALE_ID, Inject} from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale:string) {}

doIt()
{
     const decimalPipe=new DecimalPipe(this.locale)
     return decimalPipe.transform(3.141516,'1.0-3')
}
```

But you can also simply import [formatNumber](https://angular.io/api/common/formatNumber) and use it

```
import { formatNumber } from '@angular/common'; 
import { LOCALE_ID, Inject} from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale:string) {}

doIt()
{
     return formatNumber(3.141516,this.locale,'1.0-2')
}
```

NOTE: From Angular 8, Angular export the functions formatNumber, formatCurrency, formatPercent and formatDate (from @angular/common) that are the same functions pipes use